# How to create form that will add content in drupal?

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-fapi

I can create form with drupal forms api, but I don't know how to do hook to edit or add the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `form_submit` handler, you can write the contents of your form variables (such as `$form_state`) [to the database](http://drupal.org/node/751826), or [send an email](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Drupal-Module-Handling-Forms-with-the-Forms-API-FAPI--P1038.html), and so on.

See http://drupal.org/node/751826 for details on submitting forms.